# How can I get the correct answer show in distance (KM)?

Tags: java

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Enter the TIME in MINUTES: ");
    int minutes = input.nextInt();
    
    input.close();
    
    double hours = (double) (minutes / 60);
    double distance = (double) (50 * hours);
    
    System.out.println("Distance traveled (KM) is " +distance);
```

Here is my sample program and I need to convert the inputted minutes into hours then convert it into distance traveled, but the output doesn't look like what it is supposed to be.

```
Enter the TIME in MINUTES: 45 
Distance traveled (KM) is 0.0
```

I'm really confused and I would definitely be glad if someone would help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look the below code and find what's wrong in your code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the TIME in MINUTES: ");
        float minutes = input.nextInt();
        input.close();

        float hours = minutes / 60;
        float distance = 50 * hours;
        System.out.println("Distance traveled (KM) is " +distance);
    }
}
```